# what comes after a Millinillion and what are the patterns necessary to continue?

Tags: terminology

For example there is a PDF https://www.hoffkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Placenamesthrugoogol.pdf that lists all of the names of numbers up to a centillion, a 1 with 303 0s after it, with the rules:

2=bi, 3=tri, 4=quad, 5=quin, 6=sex,
7=sept,8=oct,9=non,10=deci,20=vigin.

Tip:
Prefixes un-, duo-, tre-, quattuor-, quin-, sex-, sept-, octo-,
and novem-, appear to modify TEN (deci) to make 11 to 19.

so based off that, what would be the number [not actual number but category obviously] after centillion? micentillion, then bicentillion etc., then decicentillion, undecicentillion etc. all the up to something like "2-centillion"? And if so what would that look like?

For context:

my use case is to try to make a number to word converter, that would allow one to constantly type in [or randomly generate] a huge number and it would give the spelling of it, like https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/conversions/numberstowords.php but not limited by 200 digits

In wikipedia it says that the limit is a Millinillion https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers

that only goes up to 10^3003, however by reasonable limit is at least to calculate 10^1000000 if possible [10 with 1 million 0s after it], where can I find the general pattern after a millinillion?

Comment: @311411 so what other tag is suitable

Comment: I think "terminology": Questions on the usage and meaning of words in mathematics, the names for mathematical entities, and other such questions.

Comment: Have you read the wikipedia article on this:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers  It includes a section "Extensions of the standard dictionary numbers"

Comment: @Joe ya it doesnt say whats directly after a centillion

Comment: It does. It claims "Uncentillion" is $10^{306}$

Comment: @Joe: excellent comment. To the OP, note that the wikipedia article implies rightly, but very politely, that nobody cares - why do you care?

Comment: @RobArthan To be fair, I used to love this stuff when I was in high school, so ...

Comment: @Joe  thanks I actually didnt even notice that part, its actually very helpful, thank you

Comment: @RobArthan Im trying to make a number to word converter that would allow somoene to type in as many numbers as possible and give the result in words

Comment: @Joe I guess now the next question would be what comes after a Millinillion and how to calculate it [at least what comes **directly** after a Millinillion, meaning the next in the sequence [3 0s later only] and see if theres another pattern after that etc.]

Comment: OK: I didn't mean to sound as disparaging as I did and I am sure it's a fun programming project. Of course, the words that people actually use in practice are verbal scientific notation: "ten to the four hundred and fifty-nine" for example.

Comment: I have no idea. You may need to try to get access to: The Book of Numbers, J. H. Conway and R. K. Guy, New York: Springer-Verlag, 1996, pp. 15–16. ISBN 0-387-97993-X

Comment: These naming conventions are poorly standardized, as already the distinction of meanings of "billion" in American English and British English illustrates.  Also, your Question has a decidedly open-ended nature; one can always ask "what would come next?.  Given the Comment that you are interested in "a number to word converter", I recommend editing that context into the body of the Question.  You can then give a realistic limit to what you ask for terminology since there is a dependence on what digits a human can type in a lifetime (or a day).

Comment: A table by its nature must come to an end. Wikipedia chose millinillion as the end of that table, but that was an arbitrary choice. Re-read the paragraph _before_ the table of Conway-Wechsler numbers. It explains how to continue going after millinillion. Also see the answer to [Why doesn't the Conway-Wechsler system have a largest number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508395/139123)

Comment: @DavidK yeah your right I didn't see `and 10^29,629,629,633, the 9,876,543,210th "-illion" number, equals one "nonilliseseptuagintaoctingentillitresquadragintaquingentillideciducentillion".` maybe I should close the question now?

Comment: You could just post an answer to your own question

Comment: @Joe  I could, although even after reading it I still wasn't able to fully figure out the exact pattern for determining when to add the "illions" etc., do you think you would be able to post an answer explaining a basic method / formula [that could be used in programming etc.] to calculate the "illions" when going past a millinillion?

Answer (score 1):

**Numbers after Millinillion**
They CAN keep going up after Millinillion, but you would have to repeat the patterns throughout these numbers to reach another -illinillion: Centillion's, Ducentillion's, Trucentillion's, Quadgringentillion's, Quinquadringentillion's, Sescentillion's, Septingentillion's, Octingentillion's, and Nongentillion's. Then, you finally reach Millinillion.
Repeat with those numbers to reach Billinillion. After that comes a Trillinillion, Quadrillinillion, Quintillinillion, Sextillinillion, Septillinillion, Octillinillion, Nonillinillion, and on...

Comment: There is a Decillinillion, Undecillinillion, Duodecillinillion, Tredecillinillion, Quattuordecillinillion, Quindecillinillion, Sexdecillinillion, Septendecillinillion, Octodecillinillion, Novemdecillinillion, and then Vigentillinillion. Just keep repeating this until you reach Millillion. This number is followed by over 1,000,000 ZEROS!!!!